# Combobox autocomplete mode low performance(Alternative way?)

Tags: c#

I'm populating a combobox with 5000 rows from SQL Server.

If I use `AutocompleteMode SuggestAppend`and `AutoCompleteMode ListItems` the form makes about 10 seconds to open.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there any alternative way like texting in a textbox and showing results from below?

**Code:**

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM CustomerMaster ORDER BY name", con);

SqlDataReader sqlReader2 = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader();

while (sqlReader2.Read())
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(sqlReader2["name"].ToString());
}

sqlReader2.Close();
```

If I don't use autocomplete mode, then form opens fast.

Comment: I'd recommend a textbox...and give them a search button using the LIKE filter and a grid...that way you dont pull all the records in the database

Comment: OK nice thought i will try that!

Comment: How many names are there in the data base?  Is there an index on name which you are sorting on?

Comment: There are 5500 names. And yes i'm sorting the index of name